# How to get horizontal rules around title and left-aligned author details?

Tags: titles, titlesec, rules, author

I want to format the title and author section of my report like the authors have done in the image below.

[image]

I have tried putting two horizontal rules above and below the title, but, if I do this, the title is not vertically centered between the rules. I don't know how to go about left aligning the author details.

```
\title{\bf \Large \rule{\textwidth}{2pt} Here is my title! \rule{\textwidth}{2pt}}
\author{Smithy \\ smithy@outlook.com}
\date{} 
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

If anyone could help me with this, I'd be very grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `titling` package supplies with tools for customising the `\maketitle` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}\begin{center}\Large\bfseries}
\posttitle{\end{center}\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}}
\preauthor{\begin{center}\large}
\postauthor{\end{center}}

\title{ Here is my title!}
\author{Smithy \\ smithy@outlook.com}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. How would I go about left-aligning the author details?

Comment: The whole thing, or just the e-mail address?

Comment: The name on the left and the email on the right, as in the image I uploaded. Thanks!

Comment: Also, is the title vertically centered using this method automatically, or will I have to use the `\vspace` command?

Comment: It is vertically centred, as far as I can say, but there's always the problem of letters with ascenders or descenders which may produce a visual effect. If need, you may insert  some \vspace  in pretitle or posttitle. If you look at the documentation, you have some more tools (`\maketitlehooka`, `\maketitlehookb`, &c.)

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{\hrule\vspace{1ex}{\bfseries\Large Here is my title!}\vspace{1ex}\hrule}
\author{Smithy \\ smithy@outlook.com}
\date{} 
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some notes:

- In most cases, don't put anything before `\documentclass`.
- Don't use `\bf`!
- This is dirty. IMHO you should only have `\title{Here is my title!}` and redefine `\maketitle`.

---

So I post a proposal which I think is better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@maketitle{%
\centering\hrule\vspace{2ex}{\bfseries\Large\@title}\vspace{2ex}\hrule\par
\begin{center}
    \large\@author
\end{center}
}
\makeatother
\title{Here is my title!}
\author{Smithy \\ smithy@outlook.com}
\date{} 
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you want to have the arrangement of the name and the email as desired, you can use `\hfill` instead of `\\`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@maketitle{%
\centering\hrule\vspace{2ex}{\bfseries\Large\@title}\vspace{2ex}\hrule\par
\begin{center}
    \large\@author
\end{center}
}
\makeatother
\title{Here is my title!}
\author{Smithy \hfill smithy@outlook.com}
\date{} 
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! How would I left align the author name, and right align the author email as in the image in my post?

Comment: @Henry You can use `\hfill`.

Comment: Is there any chance you could update your answer with this? I've never used the `\hfill` command.

Comment: @Henry I just do it.